# Async await with promises

Tags: meteor, async-await, ecmascript-next

I would like to know why this code using `async` and `await` does not work.

```
// I promisified `github.users.get` which is asynchronous
function getUserData() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    github.users.get({}, function (err, res) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(res)
      }
    });
  });
}

// Similar to above
function getUserEmails() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    github.users.getEmails({}, function (err, res) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(res)
      }
    });
  });
}

(async function () {
  let github = new GithubAPI({version: '3.0.0'});
  github.authenticate({
    type: 'oauth',
    token: // auth token
  });

  let userData = await getUserData(); // stuck
  let emails = await getUserEmails();

  // do something
}());
```

The code never continues beyond `let userData = await getUserData();`. It is stuck there.

What am I doing wrong? I am using Meteor 1.3.1.

Comment: The code looks right to me.. can you confirm that `resolve`/`reject` is getting called? (for example `console.log('resolving', res); resolve(res);`)

Comment: FYI, async/await is not part of ES7,